GeoServer startup script is getting killed in Debian
I have a GeoServer Jetty setup on my machine, but when I'm trying to run it using sh startup.sh it is getting killed.
What might be the reason ?
$ sh startup.sh
GEOSERVER DATA DIR is /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir
2024-07-23 11:11:03.085:INFO::main: Logging initialized @298ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2024-07-23 11:11:03.451:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.52.v20230823; built: 2023-08-23T19:29:37.669Z; git: abdcda73818a1a2c705da276edb0bf6581e7997e; jvm 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04.2
2024-07-23 11:11:03.482:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///usr/share/geoserver/webapps/] at interval 1
2024-07-23 11:11:04.034:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2024-07-23 11:11:04.111:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2024-07-23 11:11:04.111:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2024-07-23 11:11:04.112:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
11:11:05 CONFIG [geoserver.logging] - Logging policy: Log4J2
23 Jul 11:11:06 CONFIG [geoserver.logging] - Log4j 2 configuration set to DEFAULT_LOGGING.xml
2024-07-23 11:11:06.436:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Killed


what version of Java are you running?

I'm using openjdk 11.0.23 2024-04-16

That's mighty old, I'm not sure we even support JDKs that old - try 17 or 22

I am running GeoServer 2.25.2 on Windows with Eclipse Adoptium: 11.0.23 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM). No problem.
